AWS Lambda with SAM and Flask won't serve binary static files
I have a MWE Amazon Lambda and Flask that serves static files in the static/ directory just fine, but it won't serve binary files due to the binary restriction on the AWS Lambda API gateway. The way around this is that you are supposed to encode binary files as Base64. My static handler does that, but the AWS API is not turning the base64 encoded files back to binary.
Here is my template.yaml file for SAM:
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  lambda-flask -   Sample SAM Template for lambda-flask with AWS Lambda Powertools

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    Tracing: Active
  Api:
    TracingEnabled: true

Resources:
  FlaskrApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      BinaryMediaTypes:
        - image/x-icon
        - image/png
        - image/jpeg
        - audio/mpeg
        - application/octet-stream
      Cors:
        AllowMethods: "'OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE'"
        AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"

  FlaskrFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: flaskr/
      Handler: lambda_handler.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.13
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        RootPath:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref FlaskrApi
            Path: /
            Method: ANY
        ProxyPath:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref FlaskrApi
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY

Outputs:
  FlaskrApi:
    Description: API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage
    Value: !Sub "https://${FlaskrApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
  FlaskrFunction:
    Description: Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !GetAtt FlaskrFunction.Arn
  FlaskrFunctionIamRole:
    Description: Implicit IAM Role created for the function
    Value: !GetAtt FlaskrFunctionRole.Arn

And here is my file flaskr/lambda_handler.py:
import os
import logging
from apig_wsgi import make_lambda_handler
from flaskr.flaskr import app

lambda_handler = make_lambda_handler(app,binary_support=True)

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s "
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

and here is the file flaskr/flaskr/init.py:
from .flaskr import app

and finally here is the file flaskr/flaskr/flaskr.py:
from flask import Flask, current_app, Response, send_file,  request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)  # create the application instance :)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<path:filename>')
def serve_static(filename):
    try:
        if filename.endswith('.jpg'):  # Or any other binary file type
            with open(os.path.join(app.static_folder, filename), 'rb') as f:
                image_binary = f.read()
            encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_binary).decode('utf-8')
            return Response(encoded_image, mimetype='image/jpeg')
        return app.send_static_file(filename)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return {"error": "File not found"}, 404
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}, 500

Files in flaskr/flaskr/static get served, but the .jpg files there are served as BASE64-encoded text blobs. The API gateway is supposed to change them back, but it's not.
You can find the whole project here: https://github.com/simsong/lambda-flask
I also tried modifying my lambda handler to print events before they are returned. Here is an example of an event return that is NOT being base64 decoded, but being passed as-is:
    result={
    "statusCode": 200,
    "multiValueHeaders": {
        "Content-Disposition": [
            "inline; filename=facebook.png"
        ],
        "Content-Type": [
            "image/png"
        ],
        "Content-Length": [
            "443"
        ],
        "Last-Modified": [
            "Tue, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT"
        ],
        "Cache-Control": [
            "no-cache"
        ],
        "ETag": [
            "\"315532800.0-443-4173729184\""
        ],
        "Date": [
            "Mon, 30 Dec 2024 04:46:37 GMT"
        ]
    },
    "isBase64Encoded": true,
    "body": "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"
}

I would really like this MWE to work. Right now it's just a MWE for testing purposes.

When sending client request to APIGW, did you also include Accept header with type that matches with Content-Type returned by the handler? Does it work if you also set BinaryMediaTypes as */*? If the response from handler is similar to result, the base64 string should be converted to binary

What are your initial client request headers? You mentioned, responses are just text, but what are the final response headers client receives?  How API Gateway converts the response payload
